# How to use nested forms in Rails with paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Running RUby 1.9.3-p194 and Rails 3.2.3 and the latest paperclip gem.

I am following the tutorial here:
[Multiple File Uploads with Paperclip & Rails 3 (Screencast)](http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/paperclip-with-rails-3)

I've set up a post to have multiple images.  And I build 5 image objects in my controller.

However, this does not appear to show up in my view:

```
  <% f.fields_for(:postimages) do |asset_fields| %>
     <p><%= asset_fields.file_field :image %></p>
  <% end %>
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Pretty sure you need an = on that first line, so <%= f.fields_for(:postimages) ... %>

Comment: @ShaneO'Connor - looks like that fixed it and is a bug in the tutorial code and other code on the web.  I was pulling my hair out re: this "bug"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you need an = on that first line, so

```
<%= f.fields_for(:postimages) ... %>
```